# nginx displaying welcome page instead of application webpage

Tags: nginx, webserver

Welcome to nginx!
If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.

For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
Commercial support is available at nginx.com.

Thank you for using nginx.

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default is only a directory

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}

server {

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name iitians.xyz www.iitians.xyz; # managed by Certbot


    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/iitians.xyz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/iitians.xyz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot



}
server {
    if ($host = www.iitians.xyz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = iitians.xyz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name iitians.xyz www.iitians.xyz;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_static on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    server {
        # If your host is not IPv6 ready use listen 80; here.
        # Add ipv6only=off to your listen directive that has default_server.
        # Or this one if this is your only vhost. Do not add it to both!
      listen [::]:80;
      server_name iitians.xyz;

      location / {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
      }
    }

      # Redirect https://www.diaspora.example.org to https://diaspora.example.org
    server {
      listen [::]:443 ssl;  # Same rules as for listen [::]:80 apply.

      server_name www.iitians.xyz;

      location / {
        return 301 https://www.iitians.xyz$request_uri;
      }

      # SSL setup

          # This file should also include any necessary intermediate certificates.
          # For example for StartSSL that would be https://www.startssl.com/certs/class1/sha2/pem/sub.class1.server.sha2.ca.pem
          # For Let's Encrypt use /etc/letsencrypt/live/diaspora.example.org/fullchain.pem
          # and /etc/letsencrypt/diaspora.example.org/privkey.pem
      ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/iitians.xyz/fullchain.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/iitians.xyz/privkey.pem;

          # Taken from https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS
          # You might want to make these global

          # generate with openssl dhparam 2048 > /path/to/dhparam.pem
      ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
      ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
      ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128:AES256:AES:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK';
      ssl_session_timeout 5m;
      ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
      ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    }

    # Actual proxy

    server {
      listen [::]:443 ssl; # Same rules as for listen [::]:80 apply.
      server_name www.iitians.xyz;
      root /home/diaspora/diaspora/public;

        # Configure maximum picture size
        # Note that Diaspora has a client side check set at 4M
      client_max_body_size 5M;
      client_body_buffer_size 256K;

        # SSL setup

        # This file should also include any necessary intermediate certificates.
        # For example for StartSSL that would be https://www.startssl.com/certs/class1/sha2/pem/sub.class1.server.sha2.ca.pem
        # For Let's Encrypt use /etc/letsencrypt/live/diaspora.example.org/fullchain.pem
        # and /etc/letsencrypt/diaspora.example.org/privkey.pem
      ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/iitians.xyz/fullchain.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/iitians.xyz/privkey.pem;

        # Taken from https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS
        # You might want to make these global

        # generate with openssl dhparam 2048 > /path/to/dhparam.pem
      ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

      ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
      ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128:AES256:AES:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK';
      ssl_session_timeout 5m;
      ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
      ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;

        # Proxy if requested file not found
      try_files $uri @diaspora;

      location /assets/ {
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
      }

        # Camo support
        #location /camo/ {
        #  proxy_redirect off;
        #  proxy_pass http://camo/;
        #  break;
        #}

       location @diaspora {
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
         proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
         proxy_redirect off;

         proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
       }
    }

      # Proxy destination
      # Add as many server directives as you want
      # Also takes a socket, like unix:/path/to/some/socket.sock
    upstream diaspora_server {
      server unix:/home/diaspora/diaspora/tmp/diaspora.sock;
    }

      # Camo support
      #upstream camo {
      #  server 127.0.0.1:8081;
      #}  

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Comment: What file do you want to be displayed? Can you show its content?

Comment: its ruby on rails application installed on the server with ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you been able to resolve it?

Comment: Its ip4 & ip6 issue. You need to do the below `listen [::]:443 ssl default_server ipv6only=off; # Same rules as for listen [::]:80 apply.` If this resolves the issue otherwise I will share complete configuration